# Output morse code from a file

Tags: matlab

My program is supposed to read a text file and output it in morse code.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function morse(filename)

% MORSE converts text morse code and writes it to a file



% Defining Characters & Numbers
    A = ['.-'];
    B = ['-...'];
    C = ['-.-.'];
    D = ['-..'];
    E = ['.'];
    F = ['..-.'];
    G = ['--.'];
    H = ['....'];
    I = ['..'];
    J = ['.---'];
    K = ['-.-'];
    L = ['.-..'];
    M = ['--'];
    N = ['-.'];
    O = ['---'];
    P = ['.--.'];
    Q = ['--.-'];
    R = ['.-.'];
    S = ['...'];
    T = ['-'];
    U = ['..-'];
    V = ['...-'];
    W = ['.--'];
    X = ['-..-'];
    Y = ['-.--'];
    Z = ['--..'];
    period = ['.-.-.-'];
    comma = ['--..--'];
    question = ['..--..'];
    slash_ = ['-..-.'];
    n1 = ['.----'];
    n2 = ['..---'];
    n3 = ['...--'];
    n4 = ['....-'];
    n5 = ['.....'];  
    n6 = ['-....'];
    n7 = ['--...'];
    n8 = ['---..']; 
    n9 = ['----.'];
    n0 = ['-----'];

    text = upper(text);
    vars ={'period','comma','question','slash_'};
    morsecode=[];
    for i=1:length(text)
        if isvarname(text(i))
        morsecode = [morsecode;eval(text(i))];
        elseif ismember(text(i),'.,?/')
            x = findstr(text(i),'.,?/');
            morsecode = [morsecode;eval(vars{x})];
        elseif ~isempty(str2num(text(i)))
            morsecode = [morsecode;eval(['n' text(i)])];
        elseif text(i)==' '
            morsecode = [' '];
        end
        morsecode = [morsecode;eval(text(i))];
    end
     code = morsecode;
    if exist('file','var')
        fprintf(code, '%c')
    end
```

Comment: Ok - and what is your question?

Comment: What is it doing that you don't expect? What's your input file?

Comment: that's some nasty use of `eval` and `isvarname`, you're better off using the ascii values and using a cell array for storing the morse codes OR using a [switch case](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/switch.html)

Comment: And your question is, "How could you have written this even more poorly?" Kidding, but it is completely unnecessary to use eval here. Gunther is right.

Comment: i have NO idea what to use, i have little to no MATLAB knowledge.

Comment: how do you write - if 'A' is in a file, write '.-' to the file

Comment: Just out of curiosity: If you have *little to no* Matlab knowledge, why use it for a project like this?

Answer (score 2):

Despite the terrible question, it *is* a nice project imo and got me thinking: How can you do this text-to-morse conversion in an elegant way. This lead me inevitably to the following implementation (to OP: take my humble piece of code and learn from it).

The nicest quirk imo in there is the one-liner with [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) (split that code over more lines with an intermediate variable if you want to debug every step).

> text2morsefile.m :

```
function text2morsefile(txt,filename)
    fid = fopen(filename,'w');
    fprintf(fid,text2morse(txt));
    fclose(fid);
end
function m = text2morse(str)
    m=cell2mat(arrayfun(@char2morse,str,'uni',false));
end
function m = char2morse(ch)
    persistent morsemap;
    if isempty(morsemap)
        morsemap ={'   ','-.-.--', '.-..-.', NaN, '...-..-', NaN, '.-...', '.----.',...
            '-.--.', '-.--.-', NaN, '.-.-.', '--..--', '-....-', '.-.-.-', '-..-.',...
            '-----', '.----', '..---', '...--', '....-', '.....', '-....', '--...',...
            '---..', '----.', '---...', '-.-.-.', NaN, '-...-', NaN, '..--..',...
            '.--.-.', '.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '.', '..-.', '--.', '....', '..',...
            '.---', '-.-', '.-..', '--', '-.', '---', '.--.', '--.-', '.-.', '...',...
            '-', '..-', '...-', '.--', '-..-', '-.--', '--..', NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'..--.-'};    
    end
    % specify char for non-morse character:
    missingmorse_symbol = '';
    ch = double(upper(ch));
    m = NaN;
    if ch>=32 && ch<=95
        m = morsemap{ch-31};
    end
    if isnan(m)
        m = missingmorse_symbol;
    else
        % might add extra space between characters?
        m = [m ' '];
    end
end
```

Comment: The question asked for Morse code; would have it been that difficult to play the dots and dashes as sound?

Comment: The original question asked to write to a text file (and that's also what OP's code looks like it's trying to do). Playing it as sound, is just an extra option which can be easily added at the end of the  `char2morse` function

Answer (score 1):

You can start off by using the [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) function. You'd better do your periods first though, or you'll end up replacing portions of already morse-code-ized letters.

Example:

```
testString = sttrep('ABCD','A','.-');
```

will result in `testString = '.-BCD'`